# Unable to identify module smb when using with Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, smb

I am trying to read a file from remote server using smb client `pysmb` using Airflow DAG. The airflow is hosted on server . So I have installed `pysmb` on that server. But still I see this error `No module named 'smb'`

This is how I import smb in my python script

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
```

If I run the same script using my local which has `pysmb` installed, I don't see this error. I am pretty much sure I have installed same library on remote server as well. Do I need to do any extra config on the server. This I am asking since I am pretty much new to Airflow

Comment: What executor are you using with Airflow? Also, are you using docker images to run Airflow?

Comment: @bosnjak I am using PythonOperator and I am not using docker images to run Airflow

Comment: By executor I mean is it `LocalExecutor`, `SequentialExecutor` or `CeleryExecutor`?